# WebView: un módulo de la página (prestashop) no se muestra adecuadamente

Tags: android-studio, webview

estoy probando a crear una app simple con un web view. El problema viene al mostrar un módulo para customizar el producto de la tienda:

**Debería verse así:** (desde chrome para el móvil se ve bien)
[image: buena]

**Se ve así:**
[image: mala]

Este es el trozo de código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = findViewById(R.id.wb1);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);

    myWebView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.web));
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: Hola, agrega por favor como esta definido el WebView en tu layout, ese debe ser el problema. Por cierto te inviamos a realizar el [tour] del sitio, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya está solucionado con el match_parent, se me olvidó ponerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede ver que la página es responsiva, el problema es el tamaño que estas definiendo a tu `WebView`, si usas un `LinearLayout` o `RelativeLayout` como contenedor, te sugiero definir como ancho y alto el valor de `match_parent`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

Comment: Gracias! Efectivamente era esto. Que despiste.

Comment: excelente,. saludos @thertejada